# Positioning an item so that the item doesn't override the sidebar?

Tags: html, css, hover, position, positioning

I have an item (a speech bubble, made using CSS and html) that is hidden on the sidebar, and it appears when you hover over the sidebar.

[image: speech bubble when sidebar hover]

```
#sidebar .bubble {
 opacity:0.0;
 position: relative;
 background-color:#eee;
 margin: 0;
 padding:10px;
 text-align:center;
 width:180px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
 box-shadow: 0px 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25); 
 }
.bubble:after {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 content: "";  
 border-color: #eee transparent transparent transparent;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 10px;
 height:0;
 width:0;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:-19px;
 left:1em;
 }

 #sidebar:hover .bubble {
  opacity:1.1;
  position: relative;
  background-color:#eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
  width:180px;
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  box-shadow: 0px 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25); 
  }
```

And I'm haviing some trouble with the positioning. 
I like that the speech bubble appears upon sidebar hover, but it appears in the sidebar and lengthens the sidebar.

I was just wondering if there was a way to position it a little to the side, and not lengthening the sidebar, something like this?

[image: positioning]

I've tried fixed positioning and absolute positioning, but it did not work and simply caused the sidebar image under it to become bigger. Is there any possible way to position the speech bubble?

Comment: Show your html, so we can effectively help you.  Change the bubble css from `position: relative;` to `position: absolute;`, then position it where you want with `top` and `left`.  The reason things change when you use position absolute is because either the sidebar does not have `position: relative;`, or due to your `.bubble:after` css.

Comment: It should work with absolute positioning. Please create html and css here: http://jsfiddle.net/ so  we can understand your problem.

Comment: My codes won't appear on jsfiddle though..Shall i paste the link somewhere and give you a direct link to the code? @MarcBachmann

Comment: You can find my email [here](https://www.npmjs.org/~marcbachmann).   
I'm also on [github](https://github.com/marcbachmann).

Answer (score 0):

There is such way u can use **posotion: absolute** on the bubble and **position: relative** on the navigation container. Keep in mind that elements with absolute positioning will be "non-excisting " for the other elements so u must give them z-index: 3/*put any number u like above 2*/  . To "remove" the bubbles from the page use **display: none** but first position them fine. If u find it difficult ask for help again :D